# Converter not working when DataTemplate is loaded in code behind

Tags: c#, data-binding

I loaded the datatemplate for image column in code behind . Please refer the below code snippet,

```
        FrameworkElementFactory fef = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
        Binding bind = new Binding() { Path=new PropertyPath(imagecolumn.MappingName),Converter = new StringToImageConverter(),Mode=BindingMode.TwoWay };         
        fef.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty,new Binding(imagecolumn.MappingName));
        DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = fef };            
        this.imagecolumn.CellItemTemplate = template;
```

But my  converter is not invoked.  I need to load different images in each  row of the column .   Am i missed anything ? Please share any idea

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate a new `Binding` but you never use it. Do this:

```
    FrameworkElementFactory fef = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
    Binding bind = new Binding() { Path=new PropertyPath("MappingName"),Converter = new StringToImageConverter(),Mode=BindingMode.TwoWay,Source=imagecolumn };         
    fef.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, bind); // here you just created 
    //another instance of Binding instead  of using your bind variable
    DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = fef };            
    this.imagecolumn.CellItemTemplate = template;
```

EDIT:
Have a look at [`FrameworkElementFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx). In the remarks it sais:

> This class is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates, which are subclasses of FrameworkTemplate such as ControlTemplate or DataTemplate; not all of the template functionality is available when you create a template using this class. The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class.

Maybe you should do it the recommended way.

Comment: I edited the `Binding` to point to the `MappingName` property of `imagecolumn`. Try it.

Comment: The MappingName is passed to  converter . But i need to pass its value i.e Record.Data.CountryName which is defined in xaml